# How to organize my code?

Tags: laravel, optimization, architecture, laravel-5

I'm still in a learning phase with PHP and Laravel 5 and since I upgraded to L5, I struggle with where my code belongs to. There are so many files and folders which seem to have the same purpose or at least are very similar. There are Commands, Controllers, Events, Services, Requests, etc. I give an example with my workflow and where I would place the code and I hope you guys can comment on that and correct/help me.

---

### Situation

I want to register a new user in my application and send a welcome e-mail when he registered successfully.

### Workflow

1. **Controller (UserController):** Returns requested view (register).
2. **Request (RegisterRequest):** The "RegisterRequest" validates the entered data.
3. **Controller (UserController):** Passes the validated data to the "UserRegistrar" (service) in 'App/Services'.
4. **Service (UserRegistrar):** Creates a new user and saves it to the database.
5. **Controller (UserController):** Fires the "UserWasRegistered" Event.
6. **Event (UserWasRegistered):** This Event call the "SendWelcomeEmail" Command.
7. **Command (SendWelcomeEmail):** This Command will send/queue the welcome e-mail.
8. **Controller (UserController):** Redirects the user to a view with the information that he has been registerd successfully and a message has been send to him.

### Logic

Okay, let's discuss some logic:

- **Controller:**

  - Doesn't hold much code.
  - Mainly there to return views (with requested data).
  - Handles workflow and "connects" modules (Services, Requests, Events).
- **Request:** Validates the data for a specified request
- **Service:** A service "does" something. For example it's doing requests to the database.
- **Event:** An Event is a central place to call one or more tasks if it is fired (SendConfirmationMail, SendWelcomeMail).
- **Command:** Mainly there to handle the logic for ONE certain task. For example sending a confirmation mail. Another command will hold the logic for sending the welcome mail. Both commands are called in the Event described before.
- **Repositories:** *What is that?!*

---

So this is what I understand. Please help me and feed me with information.

Thanks,
LuMa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague and will likely attract downvotes as being "too broad". That said, here's my take on this...

The biggest issue I see is that your application structure is very different from the recommended L5 structure - or even the standard MVC structure - that it's no wonder you're getting confused.

Let's talk about your "Logic" section:

- **controller** - you're on the right track here. The controller is the glue between your models and your views. It can do *some* processing, but most should be offloaded to classes that handle specific tasks.
- **request** - what is this? L5 includes a `Request` class that includes methods for examining the HTTP request received from the client. Are you talking about subclassing that? Why? If your idea of a "request" class is primarily concerned with examining input, you can either do that in your model (ie. validating stuff before sticking it in the database) or in your controller (see the [L5 docs on controller validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation))
- **service** - again, what is this? You talk about "doing requests to the database", but L5 provides a class for that (`DB`). At a higher level, database access should primarily be done through models, which abstract away most of the low level database access. As for other services, what I usually do is create *libraries* to perform specific processing. For example, my application has a particular third party project management application that it accesses via an API. I have a library for that, with methods such as `getProject` or `createProject`.
- **event** - An event is a way of ensuring that some code is called when the event happens, without a whole lot of messing about. It sounds like you have the right idea about events.
- **command** - again, it sounds like you have the basic idea about commands.
- **repositories** - these are way of abstracting the connection between a resource (primarily the database, but it can apply to other resources too) and the code that uses the resource. This gives a way to switch the underlying resource more easily if you (for example) decide to change database servers in the future. They are optional.

You also haven't mentioned anything about **models**. L5 provides an excellent way to deal with your data in understandable chunks via `Eloquent` models - this will make your life *much* easier.

My suggestion is this: start small. Build a simple MVC application with L5 - A model (to save some data), a view (to display the data), and a controller (to put the model & view together by handling the client request). Once you have that, start extending it.

There are tutorials out there that will give you this basic structure for Laravel - most are for Laravel 4, but see if you can follow the basic ideas and build something similar for Laravel 5.